# How to open public access to postgresql deployed on okteto?

Tags: postgresql, okteto

I deployed `postgresql` to okteto with the following configurations:

[image]

And then I add

```
  annotations:
    dev.okteto.com/auto-ingress: "true"
```

to the `service/postgresql`.

Now the dashboard shows:

[image]

But if I clicked the link above, it shows `my environment is ready...` thing. And if I tried to connect the url with adminer, it would fail.

[image]

## How can I connect to the postgresql from public network?

Thanks in advance!

### PS: I want my `adminer` deployed on heroku can connect to it without port forwarding.

Currently I can only enable the public accessing with **port forwarding** that as shows from the okteto log:

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace your-namespace svc/postgresql 5432:5432 &
PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U okteto -d okteto -p 5432
```

Answer (score 5):

Okteto Cloud doesn't support exposing non-https ports through the auto-ingress feature, it's only meant for services.

In the particular case, you get the error because it's expecting a deployment on port `8080` (the default port when it can't find the deployment behind). I'll work with the team to update the docs and to have that kind of situations give you a clear error message.

The scenario should work if you deploy `adminer` in the same Okteto Cloud namespace as your DB. Any reason why you are running it on Heroku?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There is a long story that I deploy `adminer` on heroku, but forget it.  I can connect the `postgresql` in Okteto with **port forwarding** and it works pretty good.

Comment: You can now also deploy PGAdmin directly from the Okteto Cloud catalog.

Comment: Thank you @Ramiro, I've also deployed adminer to okteto. And will try deploy PGAdmin later. By the way, okteto is blocked by GFW recently, sad.

Comment: You can also use port-forwarding, I wrote a post on that yesterday, in case it's helpful https://okteto.com/blog/connecting-to-database-with-port-forwarding/